# Why is there more latency when accessing an App Engine service with a custom domain?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've added a custom domain to an App Engine project. The TTFB of requests to that project's service on the *.appspot.com domain is under 15ms. Accessing the service via the custom domain, however, takes about 80ms. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Hello @Ricky, is this happening in australia-southeast1 or asia-northeast1 regions? You may check this [issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64458939). Let me know.

Comment: Maybe DNS lookups?

Comment: Holy crap I just found we are running into the same thing. All the other times seem to be about the same, but TTFB is like an extra 50 ms with a custom domain! I guess it is time to investigate some sort of CDN. Thanks for the question, it was helpful!

Comment: @Fady I think it'll be good to post your link as the answer to this question. It'll increase visibility.

Comment: Did you try the workaround here? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64458939#comment28

Comment: @ahong Yes! I wrote that comment! haha

Comment: Haha, makes sense now. Do you think your own workaround can be the answer to this question?

Comment: @ahong I don't think it's answer to the question because the workaround is basically to *not* use a custom domain with App Engine. The underlying cause is something to do with GCP's internal routing which they've known about for roughly three years but don't think is a priority to fix.

Comment: I thought the work around was " the one workaround that I know of is to use a CDN that allows overwriting the host header so you don't have to use the CNAME record provided by Google."

Answer (score 2):

According to someone who works at Google, if you set up a custom domain for an App Engine project hosted in Japan, requests are then routed via Taiwan, which increases latency. I haven't heard an explanation of *why* they do that, but regardless, GCP has known about this issue for about three years and don't seem to think it's a big problem https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64458939

Comment: This only applies to certain regions and they have a list of regions affected: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/mapping-custom-domains

Comment: People should not assume this list is complete. It did not include asia-northeast1 at the time this question was written and I wouldn't be surprised if recently added regions also have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Point mentioned in the documentation on mapping custom domain with app engine

> Using custom domains might add noticeable latency to responses that
> App Engine sends to your app's users in some regions. The regions are
> as follows:

```
us-west2
us-east4
northamerica-northeast1
southamerica-east1
europe-west2
europe-west3
asia-south1
asia-northeast1
australia-southeast1
```

Link - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/mapping-custom-domains